# FileConveyor can't find sftp transporter

Tags: fileconveyor

```
# python /root/src/fileconveyor/fileconveyor/arbitrator.py 
/root/src/fileconveyor/fileconveyor/filter.py:10: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  from sets import Set, ImmutableSet
2014-01-23 00:23:34,615 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - File Conveyor is initializing.
2014-01-23 00:23:34,621 - Arbitrator                - WARNING  - Loaded config file.
2014-01-23 00:23:34,624 - Arbitrator                - ERROR    - The transporter module 'sftp' could not be found. Tried (sftp, transporters.transporter_sftp)
TransporterAvailabilityTestError Consult the log file for details
```

I just installed fileconveyor and created a simple config.xml, but the system chokes on start up because it can't find the sftp transporter. I've verified the sftp transporter is there and has what I assume to be good permissions and ownership (I'm root, the files are owned by root and 644).

What am I doing wrong?